# Why is QGridLayout setRowStretch not honoured

Tags: qt

I am having trouble setting a row stretch 
This snippet shows what I have attempted - it is obviosly part of a larger program, but I woujld be grateful if soemone could suggest any reason why the row stretch is not honoured.

```
    QGridLayout *pxLayout = new QGridLayout();
    pxLayout->addLayout(pxFilterLayout,   0, 0);
    pxLayout->addLayout(pxTableLayout, 1, 0);
    pxLayout->addWidget(pxDetailsLabel, 2, 0);
    pxLayout->addWidget(m_pxDetailsText, 3, 0);

    pxLayout->setRowStretch(0, 10);
    pxLayout->setRowStretch(1, 80);
    pxLayout->setRowStretch(2, 10);
```

Comment: Generally speaking `setRowStretch` *is* honoured.  If you're having a problem using it then you need to explain more clearly what you're seeing and provide a [mcve] that be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Do you also set stretch for the 4th row?